# Change image on device orientation jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

so I have a task to do a mobile design website and I have to change the image every time I tilt the device.

**INSTRUCTIONS**

Create 4 layers in an HTML document, as per mock-ups above, using the images provided to you. This is
a mobile webpage.
We’ve provided image assets for both portrait and landscape orientations. The correct images should
appear depending on the user’s device orientation.
The aim of this page is to allow the user to navigate between layers by tilting the device.
Example: on the BLUE page tilting your device to the left takes you to the GREEN page and tilting it to the
right takes you to the YELLOW page.
There should also be a fading effect when transitioning between layers.

So, I was thinking about something like this but my code is not really working. Please, check the jsfiddle example below, thank you.

**Html code**

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>The orientationchange Event</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/f6g580ro/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are resizing the image using jquery, try to resize it using css media query that's more faster and stable process, use something like this in CSS:

```
 @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { /*CSS for portrait*/ }
```

and

```
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { /*CSS for landscape*/ }
```

Don't forget to use media="screen" attribute on link tag where placing css file or it won't work.

Alternatively, you can provide max-width to the image in Percentage or pixels (in case of fixed width) and height set to auto, something like this max-width:80%; height:auto; to avoid image stretch when screen resizes or orientation changes.

Further Details Refer The following link

https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I was thinking to do the same thing but correct me if I am wrong, I think I can only put 1 img for each orientation option (portrait, landscape) and in my case I need them to be changed on every direction(left, right and straight), thats why I am little confused and wanted to use jquery mobile orientation function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not so easy. There are a lot of inconsistencies across devices. You may need to switch to a better approach for this. Without reinventing the wheel, there are already some great libraries for tilt and motion detection.

Just as an example: in [Full-Tilt](https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt) are following orientations defined:

```
SCREEN_ROTATION_0        = 0
SCREEN_ROTATION_90       = M_PI_2
SCREEN_ROTATION_180      = M_PI
SCREEN_ROTATION_270      = M_2_PI / 3
SCREEN_ROTATION_MINUS_90 = - M_PI_2
```

You can get the angle and then change the page accordingly. To test the [compass](https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt/blob/master/examples/compass.html) example you need a real device.